# How do i convert a string to a quoted variable

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Lets say i want to get the documentation for a function, I'd say

```
(documentation 'foo 'function)
```

but what if I only had `foo` and `function` as strings? E.g. `"foo"` and `"function"`.

What would I have to do to them to make them usable as parameters to the `documentation` call?

[Side note: I'm using clisp, but I doubt that matters.]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `FIND-SYMBOL`, not `INTERN`. If you want to find documentation for an existing function, finding a symbol is enough. `INTERN` also creates symbols.

```
CL-USER > (find-symbol "SIN" "COMMON-LISP")
SIN
:EXTERNAL
```

Note that Common Lisp symbols are uppercase internally be default. Thus you need to use an uppercase string to find the corresponding symbol in the corresponding *package*.

Also note that there actually isn't something like a 'quoted variable'. You want to convert a string to a symbol.

Comment: So, is `(documentation (find-symbol "FOO" "COMMON-LISP-USER") (find-symbol "FUNCTION"))` the appropriate way to address the example problem? It works. I just want to make sure I understand this completely. (assuming I'd created a FOO function in the REPL).

Comment: also, re your comment about converting it to a symbol, the problem I was having was that there were like 4 different symbol forms I could convert the string to and none of the ones i tried worked (thus the question). Plus I probably wasn't upcasing. So, thanks, and thanks for the extra explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Use [INTERN](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_intern.htm) to convert a string to a *symbol*. Make sure you uppercase the strings because, unlike with symbols, the reader will not do it for you:

(tested in SBCL):

```
* (documentation 'mapcar 'function)
"Apply FUNCTION to successive elements of LIST. Return list of FUNCTION
   return values."

* (documentation (intern "MAPCAR") (intern "FUNCTION"))
"Apply FUNCTION to successive elements of LIST. Return list of FUNCTION
   return values."
```

Comment: Rainer made a good point in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25786081/1281433), in that it's probably better here to use **find-symbol**, so that you're not accidentally adding a bunch of new symbols to a package.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor `INTERN` will create the symbol only if it doesn't yet exist. So both should be equivalent, modulo typing errors, right?

Comment: But if there *was not* already a symbol with a given name, then you probably *don't* want to create it here. For instance you would not want to create `cl:foo` just because someone wrote `foo`.

Comment: Agreed. I wont delete the answer so that Rainer's keeps its context. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: Sigh, I was editing your answer, while I wanted to edit mine... Sorry for the confusion...